# Having issues with edit-tags.php not saving $_POST values for custom post_types including woocommerce product_cat

Tags: custom-taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic

I added custom fields to WooCommerce category edit form using `add_action('product_cat_edit_form_fields')` and on update action `add_action('edited_product_cat')` The fields display correctly.

On update action, the JSON request data shows correctly in the browser's console but not being saved to the database table `_options` as set to do and appears that the array key is just not existing in the php $_POST array, as if page `edit-tags.php` is not being loaded.

**NOTE** The process works fine when taxonomy is `category`

**the code on update run time**

```php
global $pagenow;
if( 'edit-tags.php' === $pagenow || 'admin-ajax.php' === $pagenow ) {

add_action('edited_product_cat', function($term_id) {
  if( array_key_exists('cmse_options',$_POST) ) {
    $field_key = $_POST['cmse_options'];
    
    $keys = array_keys($field_key);
    foreach($keys as $field_name) {
        if( isset($field_key[$field_name]) ) 
            $keys[$field_name] = $field_key[$field_name];
    }
    
    // serialize update options
    update_option('woo_cat_config_'.$term_id, $keys);
  }
});

}
```

**screen shot of console**
[image: screenshot console]

Comment: Could you share with us the ajax function that you have implemented? And what about the responses?

Comment: @BaljkaGan There's no additional AJAX process. The screenshot is just to show that the data request is sent on form update action via the core `wp_ajax` and the process via edit-tags.php runs. There just is no `$_POST` values being passed to the database.